# Automating A Function / Statement To Excute After Each PHP Statement

Tags: php

I'm not sure if it's present in PHP or not, or you might think of it a crazy or a wild idea. But somehow, it would be very convenient for me if I can make a function to execute after each statement in a PHP script.

For example:-

Normal Case:-

```
<?php

$a = 1;
$b = 2;
echo $a . "\n";
echo $b . "\n";

?>
```

This should result in:-

```
1
2
```

I want a case where I can write a function:-

```
function should_excute_after_each_php_statement() {
   echo 'a statement completed' . "\n";
}
```

and the script should result:-

```
a statement completed
a statement completed
1
a statement completed
2
a statement completed
```

Possible?

Comment: It is totally crazy. Why do you want to call a function after every statements ? What are you really trying to accomplish here ? Perhaps there's another way to solve your problem.
Suppose your code file has over 1000 lines of code. If you call function after every statement, then you're CPI will run out of memory. It can lead to horrific problems.

Comment: What's the actual use case for this? Because, yes, in abstract, it will just lead to horrific problems.

Comment: have you thought about recursion here? executing a statement after every statement will lead to an infite loop

Comment: Also for a trivial solution, create a function and execute it after each line. HTH. :D

Comment: You may use ob_start to differ displaying your page, and at the end you can parse this buffer and add whatever you want after each line

Comment: If you want this for debugging purposes, why not use xdebug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand from your question I'd say phps "[ticks](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php)" are exactly what you are looking for:. They usually come in handy for debugging purposes. Give 'em a look!